# Find the values of a and b that make f continuous everywhere

Tags: calculus

Question:

[image: Question]
.
.
.
.

What I've done so far:
[image: What I have Done]
I can't find the Y value for the last equation and I need it to answer the question. Not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A hint for you might be enough...You want the function to be continuous at $x = 2, 3$ and therefore continuous on all $\mathbb{R}$. To this end, you need: $f(2) = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2^{-}} f(x)$, and $f(3) = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 3^{-}} f(x)$ . Can you take it from here? You can solve for $a, b$ through the equations above, and the $2$ equations above can be set up from the data of the function you have. I hope it is quite clear....